# Autocomplete search is not working with toggle menu on iPhone device

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have differnt search box for desktop website and mobile devices. desktop website autocomplete function is working fine but when i am trying the same on toggle menu, menu top working and page become unresponsive.

I also created separate instances for toggle menu but it does not work, though android devices are working fine.

I am using Javascript.

Resources:

Resources:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/algoliasearch@3/dist/algoliasearchLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/autocomplete.js/0/autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
    const client = algoliasearch('HKRLNT6OTC', '0988f04b8d1d11e3f0e5053b0498aceb');
        const players = client.initIndex('Apex_Index_Name_Tier_Demo2');
        var enterPressed = false;

autocomplete('#ctl00_UCHeader1_ctl00_livesearchDevice', {}, [
    {
        source: autocomplete.sources.hits(players, { hitsPerPage: 8 }),
        displayKey: 'name',
        autofocus: true,
        showReset: false,
        showSubmit: false,
        templates: {
            //header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category"></div>',
            header: '<div></div>',
            suggestion({ url, image, showFrom, starimage, _highlightResult }) {
                return `<span>${_highlightResult.name.value}</span><span>${_highlightResult.h1name.value}</span>`;
            }
        }
    },
]);
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks, Vineet

Comment: Do you mind showing a code related to problem?

Comment: You should update your question, not post it as a comment.